# Ocaml incorrect type inference

Tags: ocaml, type-inference

I'm trying to make a typed version of React as an exercise in Ocaml.
To make it more functional, I'm passing a record as argument to render.

```
type ('props,'state) reactInstance =
  {
  props: 'props;
  state: 'state;
  updater: 'a . ('props,'state) reactInstance -> 'a -> 'state -> unit;}
and ('props,'state) reactClass =
  {
  getInitialState: unit -> 'state;
  render: ('props,'state) reactInstance -> element;}

module type ComponentBluePrint  =
  sig
    type props
    type state
    val getInitialState : unit -> state
    val render : (props,state) reactInstance -> element
  end

module type ReactClass  =
  sig
    type props
    type state
    val mkUpdater :
  props ->
    ((props,state) reactInstance -> 'e -> state) ->
      (props,state) reactInstance -> 'e -> unit
    val reactClass : (props,state) reactClass
  end

module CreateComponent(M:ComponentBluePrint) =
  (struct
     include M
     let rec mkUpdater props f i e =
       let nextState = f i e in
       let newInstance =
         { props; state = nextState; updater = (mkUpdater props) } in
       ()

     let reactClass =
       { render = M.render; getInitialState = M.getInitialState }
   end : (ReactClass with type  props =  M.props and type  state =  M.state))
```

One thing I don't understand is why the compiler can't infer the type of `updater = (mkUpdater props)` in  `let newInstance = { props; state = nextState; updater = (mkUpdater props) }`.

```
Error: Signature mismatch:
       Values do not match:
         let mkUpdater :
  props =>
  (reactInstance props state => '_a => '_b) =>
  reactInstance props state => '_a => unit
       is not included in
         let mkUpdater :
  props =>
  (reactInstance props state => 'e => state) =>
  reactInstance props state => 'e => unit
```

What's the difference between '_a and 'e ?
It looks exactly to same to me. How do I make this type check?

Comment: The error you gave is not the actual one that your file produces. The right error is "Error: This expression has type ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'd
       but an expression was expected of type
         ('e, 'c) reactInstance -> 'f -> 'c -> unit
       Type 'a -> 'b -> 'c is not compatible with type ('e, 'c) reactInstance 
"

Comment: There are multiple things that look like errors in the file, but it's hard to solve them without knowing what is the supposed semantics of your operations. The first thing that jump to me, though, is the `'a .` in the updater field, are you sure you want to use a forall here ? It doesn't seem very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A type variable `'_a` (the actual letter doesn't matter, the crucial thing is the underscore) is a so called weak type variable. This is a variable that cannot be generalized, i.e., it can be substituted with only one concrete type. It is like a mutable value, but in the realm of types.

A type denoted with a weak type variable `'_a` is not included in a type that is denoted with a generic type variable. Moreover, it even can't escape the compilation unit, and should be either hidden or concretized.

Weak type variables are created when an expression is not a pure value (that is defined syntactically). Usually, it is either a function application, or an abstraction. It is usually possible, to get rid of weak type variables by doing a so called eta-expansion, when you substitute a partially applied function to a normal function application by enumerating all function arguments, i.e., `updater = (fun props f i e -> mkUpdater props f i e)`.